# Why does R round results of values over 2 million being divided?

Tags: r

In R, Why does this result in the accurate decimal value 999999.5.

```
1999999/2
```

But this results in a rounded whole number (1000001)?

```
2000001/2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about the number of digit for printing. You can set the number of digit to print in the `print` function.

```
print(2000001/2, digits = 8)
# [1] 1000000.5
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just formatting. You can also set this option outside of the print function:

```r
1999999 / 2
#> [1] 999999.5
2000001 / 2
#> [1] 1e+06
2000001 / 2 - 1000000 # The number is still full precision
#> [1] 0.5
options(digits=10)
2000001 / 2
#> [1] 1000000.5
```

Created on 2018-06-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).